# Quickly selecting elements in the DOM

Tags: c++, dom, optimization, chess

**Background:** For one of my university courses, I am making Chess.  The GUI is already finished with hooks into a controller, all I have to do is implement the objects.  Traditionally, I would just use native structures suited to each type of object, a stack for a move history (undo supported, but not redo), 2d array/vector for the board, etc.  Part of the specification is that I have to load and save the game in a specialized XML format, so I am tempted to simply use a DOMDocument to store the game in its entirety.  This would make loading and saving extremely easy if I have a library that implements the DOM load/save actions, because I no longer have to translate between the XML and my structures.

**Problem:** Speed.  In all of the algorithms in chess, I have to do a lot of selecting by location.

**XML Format** (unchangeable):

```
<board>
        <piece type="rook" color="white" column="0" row="7"/>
        <piece type="knight" color="white" column="1" row="7"/>
        <piece type="bishop" color="white" column="2" row="7"/>
        <piece type="queen" color="white" column="3" row="7"/>
        <piece type="king" color="white" column="4" row="7"/>
        <piece type="bishop" color="white" column="5" row="7"/>
        <piece type="knight" color="white" column="6" row="7"/>
        <piece type="rook" color="white" column="7" row="7"/>
        <piece  color="white" column="3" row="6" type="pawn"/>
        <piece row="6" type="pawn" color="white" column="4" />
</board>
```

Now I have to get all piece elements and filter out the attributes, an O(n) operation.  In an array/vector implementation, I can easily achieve an O(1) time, because it's simple indexing.  The price of O(n) is just too high to pay, especially when detecting stalemate.

**How would you improve the speed?** I'm basically looking for ways index the DOM.  I've had some ideas, but how would you solve this problem?

*For reference, I'm developing in C++ and will probably use the [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) library for XML, though I'm mainly looking for ideas, not actual code (though that would be helpful).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the board for chess has fixed dimensions, I opted to go with a 2D array of `DOMNode` pointers.  It's very quick, and while it does add some code complexity, it works just fine.

I do wish I knew of another way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

You've created the speed impediment yourself by forcing yourself to use the XML structure. All this is giving you is a quick save/load, which is something which is done far less often during the game than actually playing the game. Therefore, I suggest you use your native structures to obtain the speed you want, and write serialization code to map the native structures to the XML.

I am curious about your speed issues though: O(n) vs O(1) is only a problem when n is large. Are there really going to be a large number of pieces that the O(n) searching is a problem? Time complexity is just a theoretical guide to the speed of execution. You need to keep in mind that this will be implemented, and in your implementation, tradeoffs can be OK even if they are not the theoretical best choices (i.e. chosing O(n) over O(1))

Comment: Consider the case when I calculate all possible moves on a piece that could put my king in chess.  In addition to calculating the piece's normal moving pattern, I have to calculate obstacles that would stop it moving, pieces it could capture and determine whether any piece of the opponent's could capture the king if that move was chosen.  I also then have to determine if that move would put THEIR king in check.  There's enough computation there for the big oh speed to matter.  The problem isn't the number of pieces so much as the fact of how many times it's called.

Comment: As per the speed impediment: your solution is not a solution.  I already know I can map them.  How would you tackle THIS problem?  There's more to this project than simply getting it done.  Doing it with the DOM is an entirely different project than doing it in native structures, and therefore has different value to me.